# How do i update all values of an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I change all salary values and increase them by a percentage, when each salary is a property of an object, with each object being stored in an array? E.g. increasing by 10 percent and I have to round the result up to the nearest integer:

```
raiseSalary([
    { name: "Ali", salary: 3000 },
    { name: "Rob", salary: 2000 },
    { name: "Adam", salary: 4500 },
], 10)
```

The above call should return:

```
[
   { name: 'Ali', salary: 3300 },
   { name: 'Rob', salary: 2200 }, 
   { name: 'Adam', salary: 4950 }
]
```

This is the code that I have written:

```
function raiseSalary(arr, raise) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [{}];
    } else {
        const raiseArray = arr.map((salaryObj) => {
            return (salaryObj.salaryObj / 100) * 10;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest options are `map` and return a new array, or `forEach`/`for`-loop and modify in-place. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: I'm having issue with increasing all the values of salary property by given percentage. The map method is the approach i'm taking for this.

Comment: What *specific* issue are you having? Without any code it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: If you are using the Map method, then show us the code that you have so we can see where the problem is. Stack Overflow is a place to help you with problems that you have with your existing code. Not to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just a few points

- Just as you return something when the array has zero elements, you have to return something when it has elements; in this case the modified array
- Retain the objects by using their keys and providing the data, otherwise, you end up with an array of just numbers.
- Since your aim is to raise salary by `raise` then instead of multiplying by the `raise`, in this case `10`, multiply by `100+raise`
- You do not have to hard-code `raise` since you're passing it to the function; it allows you to pass `5`, or `15` or some other raise value without changing your function.

```js
const input = [{ name: "Ali", salary: 3000 }, { name: "Rob", salary: 2000 }, { name: "Adam", salary: 4500 }],
      increment = 10;
      
function raiseSalary(arr, raise) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [];
    } else {
        return arr.map((salaryObj) => {
            return ({name:salaryObj.name, salary:(salaryObj.salary / 100) * (100+raise)});
        });
    }
}

console.log( raiseSalary(input, increment) );
```

**Alternatively ...**

Just return the modified array without testing for elements, and you can also use object destructuring.

```js
const input = [{ name: "Ali", salary: 3000 }, { name: "Rob", salary: 2000 }, { name: "Adam", salary: 4500 }],
      increment = 10;
      
function raiseSalary(arr, raise) {
    return arr.map(({name,salary}) => {
        return ({name, salary: salary/100*(100+raise)});
    });
}

console.log( raiseSalary(input, increment) );
console.log( raiseSalary([], increment) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The map method should do what you want. Note the destructuring of salaryObj to avoid manipulating the original object.

```
const percent = 10;
const multiplier = 1 + (percent / 100);
const salaries = [
  { name: "Ali", salary: 3000 },
  { name: "Rob", salary: 2000 },
  { name: "Adam", salary: 4500 },
];
const newSalaries = salaries.map((salaryObj) => {
  return {
    ...salaryObj,
    salary: salaryObj.salary * multiplier,
  };
});

console.log(newSalaries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const addRaise = (arr, pcnt) => (
  arr.map(
    ({ salary, ...rest }) => ({
      ...rest,
      salary: ( +salary * (+pcnt + 100) / 100 )
    })
  )
);

/*
// method to raise salary by "pcnt" percent
const addRaise = (arr, pcnt) => (
  // iterate over array "arr"
  arr.map(
    // destructure to access "salary"
    ({ salary, ...rest }) => ({
      ...rest,        // all other props retained as-is
      // salary updated to be 10% more than current
      salary: ( +salary * (+pcnt + 100) / 100 )
    })
  )
);
*/

const dataArr = [{
    name: "Ali",
    salary: 3000
  },
  {
    name: "Rob",
    salary: 2000
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    salary: 4500
  },
];

console.log(
  'adding raise of 10%...\n',
  'new array:\n',
  addRaise(dataArr, 10)
);
```

**Explanation**

Comments added to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach with `map` and Object spreading:

```js
const updateSalaries = (people, pct) => people .map (({salary, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  salary: Math .round (salary * (100 + pct) / 100)
}))

const people = [{name: "Ali", salary: 3000}, {name: "Rob", salary: 2000}, {name: "Adam", salary: 4500}]

console .log (updateSalaries (people, 10))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

For each element, we destructure the input to extract the `salary` from the rest of the object, and then create a new result containing the rest, but with a salary calculated from the original salary and the percentage adjustment.

Answer (score -1):

```
let userDetail=[
        { name: "Ali", salary: 3000 },
        { name: "Rob", salary: 2000 },
        { name: "Adam", salary: 4500 },
    ];
function getPercentage(num, percentage){
   return num * (percentage / 100);
}
userDetail=userDetail.map(x=> {
    return{
        ...x,
        salary:x.salary+getPercentage(x.salary,10)
    }
        })
console.log(userDetail)
```